# How to decode JSON in swift

Tags: json, swift, stock

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "FB",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-08-23 16:00:00",
    "4. Output Size": "Compact",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2017-08-23 16:00:00": {
      "1. open": "168.8400",
      "2. high": "169.3600",
      "3. low": "168.2000",
      "4. close": "168.7100",
      "5. volume": "8198515"
    },
    "2017-08-22": {
      "1. open": "168.2800",
      "2. high": "169.8700",
      "3. low": "167.1500",
      "4. close": "169.6400",
      "5. volume": "11333260"
    },
    "2017-08-21": {
      "1. open": "167.1600",
      "2. high": "168.0000",
      "3. low": "165.8200",
      "4. close": "167.7800",
      "5. volume": "11880823"
    },
    "2017-08-18": {
      "1. open": "166.8400",
      "2. high": "168.6700",
      "3. low": "166.2100",
      "4. close": "167.4100",
      "5. volume": "14933261"
    },
    "2017-08-17": {
      "1. open": "169.3400",
      "2. high": "169.8600",
      "3. low": "166.8500",
      "4. close": "166.9100",
      "5. volume": "16791591"
    },
    "2017-08-16": {
      "1. open": "171.2500",
      "2. high": "171.3800",
      "3. low": "169.2400",
      "4. close": "170.0000",
      "5. volume": "15580549"
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is how can I get all the information (ex: 4.close) from the JSON date if the days (ex: 2017-08-02) are constantly changing.

So far in my project I can only get a data of a certain date.

```
func fetchStockDataCalendar() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=\(symbol)&apikey=\(apiKey)")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("ERROR")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    //Array
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let Time = myJson["Time Series (Daily)"] as? NSDictionary  {

                        if let Day = Time["2017-06-21"] as? NSDictionary {

                            if let CloseStockData = Day["4. close"] as? String {
                                print("2017-06-21 CloseStock-> \(CloseStockData)$")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }  catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

[image: what I get]

Comment: Just a suggestion but you should not use the dates as keys, it is a value and thus it would be better to structure your data like this myJson['date'] = '2017-08-11'

Comment: It would be helpful if you replaced the JSON image with a copy/paste of the actual JSON text. It would make it much easier to read and reference.

Comment: And don't forget to delete api keys before pasting code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate over the dictionary keys and values like this:

```
if let time = myJson["Time Series (Daily)"] {
    for (key, value) in time {
        if let close = value["4. close"] {
            print("\(key) CloseStock-> \(close)")
        }
    }
}
```

Based on your comments I've added this too

```
if let time = myJson["Time Series (Daily)"] {
    for (key, value) in time {
        if let value = value as? Dictionary<String, String> {
            if let close = value["close"] {
                print("\(key) CloseStock-> \(close)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sory, Plus a doubt in value gives me 5 data how do I get one of them (ex: 4.close)

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite catch that, are you saying value is also a dictionary?

Comment: I received, but it gave me 5 values ​​as a dictionary

Comment: If it is a dictionary as well then just do something like this:
print("\\(key) CloseStock-> \\(value['4.close'])")

Comment: yes i tried that but give me error say: "type any has no subscript members"

Comment: i make because i can't send the image

Comment: make sure the key you are using is correct (i.e. where it says "4.close" above), I updated my answer but this is a different question

Comment: give me the same error: type "any" has no subscript members

Comment: sory i dont understand

Comment: look at the code I have above, do it like this:
if let close = value["4. close"] {
       print("\\(key) CloseStock-> \\(close)")
}

Comment: I put the photo below

Comment: Ok this is a casting issue, different than your original question, I'll add a newer version below but you may need to do more casts depending on what your data looks like.

Comment: Ya no worries, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is your func with the above code but as an NSDictionary. My console is showing all of the closes.

2017-10-24 CloseStock-> 256.5600

2018-02-22 CloseStock-> 270.4000

```
func fetchStockDataCalendar() {

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=\("SPY")&apikey=\(alphaApiKey)")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print ("ERROR")
        } else {
            if let content = data {
                do {
                    let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject

                    if let time = myJson["Time Series (Daily)"] as? NSDictionary  {
                        for (key, value) in time {
                            if let value = value as? Dictionary<String, String> {
                                if let close = value["4. close"] {
                                    print("\(key) CloseStock-> \(close)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }  catch  {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```